# Find the recurrence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence

I'm new to recurrence relations and I'm having trouble figuring out this problem:

Find a recurrence relation for the number of ways to make a stack of green, yellow, and orange napkins so that no two green napkins are next to each other.

I've come up with a(n)=2a(n-1)+2a(n-2) but I'm not sure if that's right/ on the right track.

Any help would be great!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math, which is more appropriate at math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your answer is correct:

- If the n'th napkin are green then n-1'th napkin could be yellow or orange and other n-2 napkin could be anything so it is 2*a<sub>n-2</sub>.
- If n'th napkin is not green it could be yellow or orange and other n-1 napkin could be anything so it is 2*a<sub>n-1</sub>.

So the final answer is a<sub>n</sub> = 2*a<sub>n-2</sub> + 2*a<sub>n-1</sub>.